# I'm getting number format exception

Tags: java, javascript

I am getting number fornat exception when i am trying to accept id in servelt
JSJP  Page :

```
    var associates = document.getElementsByName("resourceId");
    //var associates=document.getElementById(elementId).value;
        var id = "";
        for ( var i = 0; i < associates.length; i++) {
            if (associates[i].checked) {
                //alert(associates[i]);
                id = associates[i].value;
                alert(id);
                break;
            }
        }
```

I am trying to acceptid value from jsp file and send it to my dao class but i am getting number format exception when i am trying to accept the value of id

Servlet :

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("in dopost");        
    //number format exception in this line
    int associateID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    if (dao.deleteAssociate(associateID)) {
        System.out.println("deleted");
    }
    // System.out.println(associateID);
}
```

Comment: `request.getParameter("id")` refers to an HTML element with `id="id"`, not a variable named id in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get "id" of HTML webpage element, its not JavaScript variable.

On other note, I would suggest to use `instanceof` operator before doing `parseInt`.

**For example**:

```
int associateID = -1;
Object obj = request.getParameter("id");
if(null != obj && obj instanceof Number) {
    associateID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    if (dao.deleteAssociate(associateID)) {
        System.out.println("deleted");
    }
}
```